# Magento reindexes is not working - magento2

Tags: magento-2.1

I am doing reindex of all the product using

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

but when i run this command first time through me error like :

```
    PHP Fatal error:  Maximum function nesting level of '256' reached, aborting! in /var/www/html/solen_magento/vendor/magento/framework/Config/Scope.php on line 48
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /var/www/html/solen_magento/bin/magento:0
PHP   2. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() /var/www/html/solen_magento/bin/magento:25
PHP   3. Magento\Framework\Console\Cli->doRun() /var/www/html/solen_magento/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:126
PHP   4. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() /var/www/html/solen_magento/vendor/magento/framework/Console/Cli.php:49
PHP   5. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() /var/www/html/solen_magento/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:195
PHP   6. Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() /var/www/html/solen_magento/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:874
PHP   7. Magento\Indexer\Console\Command\IndexerReindexCommand->execute() /var/www/html/solen_magento/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/Command.php:257
PHP   8. Magento\Indexer\Model\Indexer->reindexAll() /var/www/html/solen_magento/vendor/magento/module-indexer/Console/Command/IndexerReindexCommand.php:38
PHP   9. Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Indexer\Fulltext->executeFull() /var/www/html/solen_magento/vendor/magento/module-indexer/Model/Indexer.php:412
PHP  10. Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Indexer\IndexerHandler->saveIndex() /var/www/html/solen_magento/vendor/magento/module-catalog-search/Model/Indexer/Fulltext.php:111
PHP  11. Magento\Framework\Indexer\SaveHandler\Batch->getItems() /var/www/html/solen_magento/vendor/magento/module-catalog-search/Model/Indexer/IndexerHandler.php:94
PHP  12. Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Indexer\Fulltext\Action\IndexIterator->rewind() /var/www/html/solen_magento/vendor/magento/module-catalog-search/Model/Indexer/IndexerHandler.php:23
PHP  13. Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Indexer\Fulltext\Action\IndexIterator->next() /var/www/html/solen_magento/vendor/magento/module-catalog-search/Model/Indexer/Fulltext/Action/IndexIterator.php:264

.
.
.
.
PHP 251. Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Indexer\Fulltext\Action\IndexIterator->next() /var/www/html/solen_magento/vendor/magento/module-catalog-search/Model/Indexer/Fulltext/Action/IndexIterator.php:204
PHP 252. Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Indexer\Fulltext\Action\IndexIterator->next() /var/www/html/solen_magento/vendor/magento/module-catalog-search/Model/Indexer/Fulltext/Action/IndexIterator.php:204
PHP 253. Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Indexer\Fulltext\Action\IndexIterator->next() /var/www/html/solen_magento/vendor/magento/module-catalog-search/Model/Indexer/Fulltext/Action/IndexIterator.php:204
PHP 254. Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute\Interceptor->getId() /var/www/html/solen_magento/vendor/magento/module-catalog-search/Model/Indexer/Fulltext/Action/IndexIterator.php:195
PHP 255. Magento\Framework\Interception\PluginList\PluginList->getNext() /var/www/html/solen_magento/var/generation/Magento/Catalog/Model/ResourceModel/Eav/Attribute/Interceptor.php:1712
PHP 256. Magento\Framework\Interception\PluginList\PluginList->_loadScopedData() /var/www/html/solen_magento/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/PluginList/PluginList.php:249
```

But when i run this command second time its successfully run and output like :

```
Customer Grid index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Category Products index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:02
Product Categories index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:01
Product Price index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:02
Product EAV index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:01
Catalog Rule Product index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Catalog Product Rule index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Catalog Search index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Stock index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
```

So based on this index is done successfully, but when i tries to search a product in magento then its not showing in searching result.

So i flushed all the cache from the admin panel.
then remove all the files from `var` dir
generate all the static files again using

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US fr_FR
```

But still its not working.

But when i edit any products from the backed and then i tries to search then its working.

Answer (score 3):

This issue has been resolved in `Magento 2.1.3` and mainline, please upgrade to 2.1.3.

> The same issue as you have:
>   https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/6722
>
> Fix for the issue:
>   https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/b75fc4f83aa2fdf093ceae25449fa0b95bbc4020